# BackgroundSubtractionGMG cannot running in Open CV 3.0

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I have been trying a background subtraction in new Open CV release, Open CV 3.0. I practice a BackgroundSubtractorGMG in Open CV 3.0 and python 2.7. I trying a code at this [BackgroundSubtractorGMG](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html). The error says:

> File "background.py", line 10, in  fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorGMG() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createBackgroundSubtractorGMG'

how do I solve this error? I appreciate for your attention and for the help thank you :-)

Comment: in 3.0, the GmG version was moved to https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib

Comment: thanks for the comment, then how to add that in Open CV 3.0? Do I need to build it?

Comment: yes, you need to build it. see the readme in contrib.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/da/df6/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_setup.html

Comment: so, I must install again of that? I already have Open CV 3.0, do I need to remove Open CV 3.0 or no? Sorry, I forget to tell that I using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. and also thank you for the reply

Comment: no, you don't need to remove anything. just add the contrib modules to your main opencv cmake settings, and rebuild the main thing.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I already sucess to build that, but when I do BackgroundSubtractor GMG its still error. where do I doing wrong?

Comment: here the screenshoot https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-6VaPu2QKyKbDNDb2JRRUJOQTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ^^ please see answer below

Answer (score 0):

once you've built opencv along with the opencv_contrib repo :

```
>>> help(cv2.bgsegm)
Help on module cv2.bgsegm in cv2:

NAME
    cv2.bgsegm

FILE
    (built-in)

FUNCTIONS
    createBackgroundSubtractorGMG(...)
        createBackgroundSubtractorGMG([, initializationFrames[, decisionThreshol
d]]) -> retval

    createBackgroundSubtractorMOG(...)
        createBackgroundSubtractorMOG([, history[, nmixtures[, backgroundRatio[,
 noiseSigma]]]]) -> retval
```

in other words, use:

```
gmg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorGMG()
```

Comment: sorry, it still showing error, the error is AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bgsegm'

Comment: that might be still the old cv2.pyd. did you run a final `make install` ?

Comment: before this 3.0 released I try the 3.0 RC 1 first, and I did not remove that because I think that is still 3.0? and I dont find the reference to remove that in the day so I build the new 3.0 released without remove RC 1. Sorry did that the problem?

Comment: hmm, imho, there is no reason to uninstall anything. `make install` should just overwrite the old one. please try again, go through your logs carefully, there might have been some error on the way.

Comment: this is the result of print cv2.getBuildInformation()) : please check this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-6VaPu2QKyKNHFsOEpSa1JCUEU/view?usp=sharing .. did the following named "unknow" (I blocked in the screenshoot) is the problem?

Comment: OpenCV is a real annoyance with renaming things, moving things to contrib. Basically if you want to play with different background subtraction algos, you have to use a combination of core and contrib. I don't quite get it.